# Retrieve current B2B Unit for Customer in Spartacus

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I want to show current B2B Unit name in the header.
What would be the correct way to retrieve B2B Unit for current customer?

What I found so far, there is a payload for /current? endpoint which is loaded on initial page load and it contains the orgUnit:

[image: Payload for /current?]

When I was trying to retrieve the Unit via CurrentUnitService, I got null value.

unit.component.ts:

```
orgUnit$: Observable<B2BUnit> = this.currentUnitService.item$;

  constructor(
    protected currentUnitService: CurrentUnitService,
  ) {}
```

unit.component.html:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="orgUnit$ | async as unit">
    <p class="d-inline-block">{{unit.name}}&nbsp;</p>
    <a href="#" class="d-inline-block">
      ({{unit.uid}})
    </a>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the B2BUnit for current customer using UserAccountFacade and by extending User model with orgUnit as follows:

unit.component.ts

```
export class UnitComponent implements OnInit {
  user$: Observable<CustomUser | undefined>;

  constructor(
    protected auth: AuthService,
    protected userAccount: UserAccountFacade
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user$ = this.auth.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
      switchMap(isUserLoggedIn => {
        if (isUserLoggedIn) {
          return this.userAccount.get();
        } else {
          return of(undefined);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}

interface CustomUser extends User {
  orgUnit?: B2BUnit
}
```

unit.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
    <p class="d-inline-block">{{user.orgUnit?.name}}&nbsp;</p>
    <a href="#" class="d-inline-block">
      ({{user.orgUnit?.uid}})
    </a>
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
  </ng-container>
```

Result:

[image]